# Selecting priors for logistic functions

Tags: distributions, logistic, gamma-distribution, conjugate-prior

I have this confusion related to how to select priors for a logistic regression

By Bayes theorem

$P(\theta|D) = \frac{P(D|\theta)P(\theta)}{P(D)}$.

Now my likelihood $P(D|\theta)$ is given by logistic function:

$P(y=1|x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\theta'x}}$.

I was thinking what sort of priors I can use for $P(\theta)$. Can I use gamma distribution for $P(\theta)$.

Will that help me to calculate:

$$\int P(\theta)P(D|\theta) d\theta$$

Comment: This thread might help. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102692/intuitive-explanation-of-bayesian-logistic-regression